# Inconsistent CSS background-repeat count on different browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, background-image, background-repeat

I'm using a repeating pattern as a background-image of a div:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; background-image:url('test_pattern.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x;"></div>
```

test_pattern.png is 25 pixels wide, so I expect it to repeat 8 times in the div that's 200 pixels wide. This is exactly what I get on Safari. However, chrome repeats the pattern slightly more than 8 times. Even stranger, when I take a snapshot of the chrome page, it turns out that the div is 220 pixels wide, not 200! Is there anyway to make this consistent on all browsers?

[image: Safari and chrome rendering:]

Comment: Might be worth trying [rems or vh](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) instead of pixels, though I can't answer why it's rendering differently as is.

Comment: It's slightly possible that there is padding being applied to the elements, and the browsers are laying out the box differently. Perhaps try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` which should make the browsers layout the padding in the same way (just in case that has something to do with the issue).

Comment: vh doesn't fix this. rem improves, but doesn't fix it (the repeat count is closer, but not exactly the same). Adding box-sizing and padding has no effect.

Comment: Did you include a css reset stylesheet?

Comment: I just added a css reset, but that didn't make a difference. I don't think the problem is with CSS. It's more likely with the way the browsers deal with screen resolution, image resolution, dpi, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Chrome's webpage was zoomed 110%. By resetting it to 100%, both Safari and Chrome render the div the same way.

What's strange is that when I zoom the Safari webpage, the background pattern continues to repeat exactly 8 times. Chrome doesn't!

Comment: That is an interesting result. I was thinking you could create a workaround. It should be possible to replicate your specific background with css's `linear-gradient`. Or maybe make a background-image to be used without repeat-x and use `background-size: 100% auto`?

Comment: Actually set `background-size: 12.5% auto`. and keep your code as it was :).

Comment: Thanks RMo, these suggestions work. However, the example I provided is just a simple test. The final product uses more complex image patterns and animated div width.